# How to pass EMR Serverless PySpark entryPointArguments as variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-step-functions, emr-serverless

I have an EMR Serverless PySpark job I am launching from a step function. I am trying to pass arguments to SparkSubmit from the entryPointArguments in the form of variables set in the beginning of the step function i.e. today_date, source, tuned_parameters, which I then use in the PySpark code.

I was able to find a partial solution in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74562238/how-to-pass-arguments-entrypointarguments-in-spark-job-using-emr-serverless) however I am trying to pass variables from the step function and not the hardcoded argument i.e.. "prd".

```
        "JobDriver": {
          "SparkSubmit": {
            "EntryPoint": "s3://xxxx-my-code/test/my_code_edited_3.py",
            "EntryPointArguments": ["-env", "prd", "-source.$", "$.source"]
          }
        }
```

Using argparse I am able to read the first argument "-env" and it is successfully returning "prd", however I am having troubles figuring out how to pass a variable for the source argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to find an answer for this question. Passing variable arguments to EMR Serverless SparkSubmit is achieved with [AmazonStateLanguage intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-arrays).

Provided that the JSON input to the StepFunction is:

```
    {
  "source": "mysource123",
    }
```

The correct way to pass this variable argument in the EntryPointArgument is:

```
"EntryPointArguments.$": "States.Array('-source', $.source)"
```

Then, using argparse one can read this variable in the PySpark job in EMR Serverless.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-source")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.source)
```

The result of the print statement is mysource123.